# Fellowship of the Ring continuity error?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

I've watched The Fellowship of the Ring several times and am convinced that this is a continuity error but have never seen it documented.  Can someone clarify whether this is an error or my eyes playing tricks?

When leaving Lothlorien Celeborn gives Aragorn a knife.  When fighting Lurz at Amon Hen he uses that knife to stab the Uruk Hai through the leg.  Lurtz then draws the blade and throws it at Aragorn who shatters it.

Towards the very end of the film during the line "Lets hunt some orc" Aragorn is shown sheathing this blade.

Have I missed something here?  To shatter a blade and then it pop up again 5 minutes later seems a very large continuity error but I'm sure I saw it shatter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aragorn didn't shatter the blade.  When Lurtz threw the blade at him Aragorn used his own sword to deflect it.  I'll see if I can get a screencap and put it up.

Okay, after several tries I cannot get a decent screen cap that clearly shows the blade.  It just looks like a flashing blur.

Comment: Thanks, I have to assume my eyes are deceiving me!  I also think this makes sense as it's unlikely that an elven blade would shatter so easily.